# Drupal $get not returning full HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I have written a Drupal module in which i am trying to call .module file via $get. It working propely.But it is returning enitire HTML page. I tried drupal_json_output since I am working on drupal -7 .I also tried using getJSON but then it stopped giving me any response at all . Please help

Here is my .module file

```
<?php

/**
* Implementation of hook_init().
*/
function ajax_privacy_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','ajax_privacy').'/userprivacy.js');
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function ajax_privacy_menu() {

  $items = array();

  $items['user/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'menu privacy',
    'page callback' => 'ajax_privacy_get_html', // Render HTML
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
/**
 * Callback to return JSON encoded data.
 */
function ajax_privacy_get_html($arg) {

 $array['text'] = $arg;
 die(drupal_json_output($array));

}
```

And here is my .js file

```
// Jquery wrapper for drupal to avoid conflicts between libraries.
(function ($) {
  // Jquery onload function.

    Drupal.behaviors.ajax_privacy = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Your JS code.

    user_id_ajax=urldetect();

    if(user_id_ajax!=-1)
    ajax_request='user/'+user_id_ajax;

    //alert(ajax_request);
    $.get('',{q:ajax_request},ajaxAction);

    return false;
    }
    };

  ajaxAction=function(response){
    alert(response);
  };

  urldetect=function()
  {
  current_url=window.location.href;
  //alert(current_url);

  user_id_temp=-1;
  slash_temp=-1;

  if(current_url.search("user/")!=-1)
  {
  user_id_temp=current_url.substring(42);
  slash_temp=user_id_temp.search("/");
  if(slash_temp!=-1)
  {
  user_id_temp=user_id_temp.substring(0,slash_temp);
  }

  }

  return(user_id_temp);
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am also clearing drupal cache if i make any changes

Comment: in drupal your output is json , try to add 'json' keyword in js file when making a call it would be something like this $.get(full_url,function(data){},'json'); looking at your js file $.get('',{q:ajax_request},ajaxAction,'json');

Answer (score 0):

```
// Jquery wrapper for drupal to avoid conflicts between libraries.
(function ($) {
  // Jquery onload function.

    Drupal.behaviors.ajax_privacy = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Your JS code.

    user_id_ajax=urldetect();

    if(user_id_ajax!=-1)
    ajax_request='user/'+user_id_ajax;

    //alert(ajax_request);
    //try adding 'json' in your $.get call
    $.get('',{q:ajax_request},ajaxAction,'json');

    return false;
    }
    };

  ajaxAction=function(response){
    alert(response);
  };

  urldetect=function()
  {
  current_url=window.location.href;
  //alert(current_url);

  user_id_temp=-1;
  slash_temp=-1;

  if(current_url.search("user/")!=-1)
  {
  user_id_temp=current_url.substring(42);
  slash_temp=user_id_temp.search("/");
  if(slash_temp!=-1)
  {
  user_id_temp=user_id_temp.substring(0,slash_temp);
  }

  }

  return(user_id_temp);
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vishwa . But it did not work :(

Comment: hi akshay i see  $.get('  ',{q:ajax_request},ajaxAction,'json'); has no url to call add page url as  $.get(' url ',{q:ajax_request},ajaxAction,'json'); the url must be full url example http://yoursite.com/user/1 the url will be what you have define in the hook_menu

Comment: for further explanation you can refer to the following link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add access callback at true :

```
$items['user/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'menu privacy',
    'page callback' => 'ajax_privacy_get_html', // Render HTML
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE // add this line
  );
```

Try this :

```
function ajax_privacy_get_html($arg) {

 $array['text'] = $arg;
 print json_encode($array);
 exit();
}
```

Comment: Will try this solution .. Thank you

Comment: Ok and let us know if this is do what exactly you want :)